# operation not permitted errron by using retrofit client

Tags: android, rest, api, retrofit2

I am trying post username credentials using the restful API using retrofit and json converter and i am running into a problem. My program is working fine its unable to make the connection. The on failure function is called and the toast message is
**socket failure: EPERM (operation not permitted)**

i have used these permissions in my manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

This is how i have handled the response call

```
Call<ResponseBody> call= RetrofitClient
            .getInstance()
            .getApi()
            .createUser(first_name,last_name,username,email,password,phoneNo);


    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override

        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            try {
                String s=response.body().toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

I am getting the error through the onfailure() method

This is the retrofitclient class that i have created

```
package com.example.usersignup_usingapi;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class RetrofitClient {
    private static final String BASE_URL="https://kamwene.000webhostapp.com/tza/tza/api/";
    private static RetrofitClient mInstance;
    private Retrofit retrofit;

    private RetrofitClient(){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    public static synchronized RetrofitClient getInstance(){
        if(mInstance == null){
            mInstance = new RetrofitClient();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
    public Api getApi(){
        return retrofit.create(Api.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the application from the device/emulator, then re-run it.